# XStream XML wrong output

Tags: xml, xstream

I've been using XStream for a couple of days, and now I have a problem with it.

I used XStream to make this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<object-stream>
   <Manga>
      <name>- Sins -</name>
      <link>http://kissmanga.com/Manga/Sins</link>
   </Manga>
   <Manga>
      <name>&amp; – and –</name>
      <link>http://kissmanga.com/Manga/–-and-–</link>
   </Manga>
</object-stream>
```

However, when I click on the XML file it shows me this:

```
- Sins -http://kissmanga.com/Manga/Sins
```

without any tags,elements and even the other object.

I would like for it to show me the whole XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<object-stream>
   <Manga>
      <name>- Sins -</name>
       <link>http://kissmanga.com/Manga/Sins</link>
   </Manga>
   <Manga>
      <name>&amp; – and –</name>
      <link>http://kissmanga.com/Manga/–-and-–</link>
   </Manga>
</object-stream>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please describe what output do you expect.

Comment: @Vertex I would like for it to show me the whole code when i opened the xml file in the browser. But instead it only shows me what i described in the message above

Comment: Ok, so you can't open the XML output in a browser? Maybe this is the problem: You're using [En dash](http://unicode-table.com/en/2013/) `\u2013`. If I replace it with [Hyphen minus](http://unicode-table.com/en/002D/) `\u002d` I can open it in Firefox.

Comment: @vertex It worked when i changed the En Dash to a Hyphen minus manually, but when I write this in java : `if(name.contains("\u2013"))` `this.name = name.replaceAll("\u2013", "\u002d");` it doesnt work

Comment: The En dash occurs also in _link_. Please make sure to replace the links too.

Comment: @Vertex oh, I forgot an else statement there. thanks for helping me. The weird thing is that when i compile the code(the same code) in another project , the En dash is present in the xml file(which opens in firefox) and I dont need to replace them. its the same code in both projects, but one produces a good xml file, while the other produces a bad xml file.